# Detect when TCP connection is lost

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I want to know when TCP connection is lost(not closed), for example when server accidentally shuts down. So I send data with outputStream.write(s); When connection is lost and I`m trying send data it should throws`SocketException`. But it throws only after second sending data. Why is this happening.

```
  void send_socket(){
            try{

                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                outputStream.write(MSG.getBytes());

            }  catch (SocketException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "connection closed");
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "error 3 - ", e);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Because TCP output is buffered.

Comment: Try to add `outputStream.flush()` after `write`

Comment: @mr.icetea That will accomplish exactly nothing. Java Socket output streams are not buffered, and `flush()` therefore has no effect.

Comment: @EJP so what I should do?

Comment: @MrStuff88 There's nothing you can do except wait for a send to throw `IOException`. You can't detect the cable pull immediately, by the nature of TCP.

Comment: NB `SocketException` doesn't mean 'connection closed'.

Answer (score 0):

The best form of detecting a disconnect or pull in TCP is to wait for the IoException to occur and take the appropriate action. the only thing TCP can facilitate for you is when the other sends the FIN which ultimately returns a -1 and tells the user that the connection has been closed with an EOFException, which i'm sure you've found out by now.

Edit: thanks for the correction. I forgot to be a little more clear.

Comment: The peer doesn't 'send -1'. It sends a FIN, which the local API returns as -1 or null or `EOFException`, depending on what you're calling.

Answer (score -1):

```golang
client                        server
======                        ======
         <-------FIN------    exit()/kill
          -------ACK------>

write()   -------PSH------>
         <-------RST------
          //RST is sent because FIN is already delivered

write()
//raise an error immediately due to RST
```

It is **right** to write a socket which has already got a `FIN`, however, it would make the peer that did a full close (which is the case of the question) and just sent the `FIN` now sends a `RST`. Then the 2nd write would raise an error immediately because it is **wrong** to write a socket that has got a `RST`. This is the TCP nature. This is why you have to send twice before knowing the server is closed.

```golang
client                        server
======                        ======
         <-------FIN------    exit()/kill
          -------ACK------>

write()   -------PSH------>
         <-------RST------
          //RST is sent because FIN is already delivered
read()
//return 0 immediately due to FIN
//or return error ECONNRESET due to RST
```

```golang
client                        server
======                        ======
write()   -------PSH------>
         <-------ACK------
read()
//waits for response
         <-------FIN------    exit()/kill
          -------ACK------>
//return 0 immediately due to FIN
```

However, the program is usually designed like this (see the two illustrations above), a write is followed by a read. The read would return 0 or an error to indicate the server is closed immediately after the server is closed. No need to write twice.

Comment: "It is right to write a socket which has already got a FIN, however, it would make the peer that sent the FIN now sends a RST": no it wouldn't. The peer might only have done a half close.

Comment: Yes. What I said is not precise. Neither were you. You should say "no it wouldn't if it is a half close, and it would if it is a full close". Just kidding. Thank you for pointing out the impreciseness. I will update the answer.